# Advice in storing sensitive data in Windows Form Application vb.net c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, encryption, connection-string

I'm currently working on a Windows Application Project and I have two problems in securing data.

**First**,I need to make a file that store a password as string which the user should enter it every time the main form loads, I tried many ways but each one has a problem:

1. Hashing the string and save it in a file, so every time user enter the password the input password will be hashed and compared with the hashed string

   **Problem:** Decompiling the application let anyone see the hashing method and file location, so he/she can create text file with hashed value of any string like 0000 and replace that file with my application file, then use the 0000 to open the application
2. Using encryption algorithm with custom encryption key

   **Problem**: key can be accessed after Decompiling the application

---

**The other problem** is for connection string of an online MySql Database that used in the application but I do not want any user see the connection string:

1. Encrypting the connection string with DataProtectionConfigurationProvider

   **Problem**: other machines can't decrypt and use the string
2. Encrypt and save the connection string in a file and decrypt and use that file when application load

   **Problem**: Decryption method can be known from source code after Decompiling

Is there anyway I can use except Obfuscating the source code?
I mean like **storing these sensitive data in a file that can be read/written by my application only**?

Feel free to write any advice about my problems and Thanks in advance

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry for that, this is my first question in stackoverflow

Comment: In this case please reader [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Try to save your files with hashed passwords in the web with read-only permissions.

Comment: What about using Windows build-in DPAPI (Data Protection API) for storing the password?

Comment: @AlexB. Ok I'm sorry again but I think that both problems may have the same solution so I asked about them together

Comment: THANKS @LeonidMalyshev ! it is really a good and very helpful solution but it requires Internet Connection every time the application loaded to retrieve the files (Note that I do not need to load MySql database every time my application loads, just in some events, so I need my application to work in ofline mode too)

Comment: Then only c++ dll. Obfuscating doesn't give any serious protection.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaps but anyone can decrypt the password using the same Windows User that encrypted the password (the same Windows build-in DPAPI user-specific key) Note that my application will be installed on a PC that many persons use it with the same user account, but only one can open it using the password

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev What do you mean by using c++ dll? Do you mean that c++ dll can not be decompiled?

Comment: @BJ Davey C++ dll also can be decompiled. But it needs more qualification than using ildasm. Anyway if you store all data locally it will take minimum time to get access. With c++ a little more, with pure c#/vb less....

Comment: Thanks @LeonidMalyshev I know anything can be decompiled but c++ will be pretty enough secure if it takes more than a free decompiler software and that is really helpful (beside I have more experience in c++ than other languages) Your Answer is really helpful and solved my two problems, I think you should make it as Answer so I can "accept" it. Thanks again.

Comment: and I still looking for anyone can provide me with a way that makes a file can be read/written by my application only

Comment: You cannot ultimately do that. You may make the life of attacker more difficult and perhaps stop an average Joe, but a determined attacker with sufficient budget will break your defences. See discussion on [security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/100129/2553). It's the same for apps or desktop apps, or web sites running on the untrusted server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save your files with hashed passwords in the web with read-only permissions. Or use dll written using unmaneged code (c++)

Comment: Also if your password file is locked you can use asymmetric keys. In this case you crypt the file with your key and the application decrypt with another. This will give about 100% protection. But only in a very specific case when the user can't add/modify password. Eg when it's not a password but license key.

Comment: How is that going to be? Why user can't add/modify password? I know about Asymmetric Encryption but I don't think that I understood you very well , Can you explain more ? please

Comment: Another way: make passwords file digitally signed. While signing use hash of your assembly. And store this hash as securestring. And also something like `#if RELEASE` to prevent debugging. So it would be possible to see program's code but to make a fake file would be much more difficult.

Comment: Signing a file does't make it read only as I know, so It won't solve the problem. Anyway , using C++ dll is the most perfect solution for this problem and I'm happy with it